# Problem in compiling android-ndk code

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I am facing an issue and would like to know why this is happening.

I have a project which consists of a `Java` file and some `JNI & C++` code files. I am building `JNI and C++` code through `cygwin` which is part of android ndk-tools. Below is my `Android.mk` file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := cube
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Testing.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := jni_opengl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni_openglcube.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := cube
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

In script above `cube` module is written in standard `C++` which do some `opengl` stuff and `jni_opengl` is written in `JNI`. Above script compiles fine but when I change line 8 `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)` to `include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)` I start getting error regarding opengl methods not found in `Testing.cpp`.

My question is why in case of `shared library`, android is able to find the references of `opengl` related method and why not when I change it to `static library`?

Answer (score 0):

Symbols needed in shared libraries are sometimes looked up at runtime. So, I think you run into the same problem, but now at runtime not link time. See if the code with the shared library runs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to have:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM
```

for your static library.

You will need to move it to your shared library section. The static section will be fine without it.

Don't forget to change:

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := cube
```

to

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cube
```

A static library is just a bunch of .o files appended together, so it doesn't get 'linked' in the same way a shared library does.

Your final Android.mk should look something like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libcube
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Testing.cpp
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := jni_opengl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni_openglcube.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcube
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -ldl -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```